Why bash is designed removing quotes while parsing a string variable with spaces?
I mean in view of designing a script system, here is the bash.
Sicne I already assigned x with "", why it cannot just treat x as quoted while parsing x ?
On the other hand, why it need to remove my quotes "" while parsing x?
So, can I change this behavior? If cannot, is there any other shell support this feature?
I just want to assign once, and then use it in many lines without adding quotes again and again
x="/a b/c.txt"

# works
basename "$x"
c.txt

# "" is removed from x, even bash has known x is a string which contains a space.  
basename $x
a


It works this way for compatibility with earlier shells that worked this way (and all the scripts that depend on this behavior, and because that's what the POSIX standard says). zsh doesn't do this (and also refuses to go along with some other bad decisions inherited from earlier shells), but it has different foibles all its own (and it doesn't work quite the way you're describing either).

Note that the shell's quoting syntax and semantics go at least as far back as 1979 ... when the Bourne shell was first released.

Seems it's hard to be done in current version.
Then what's about adding the """xxx""" to enable this feature?
If """ make sense. I should go to maillist or somewhere to fire a new feature requirement. I really want this feature.

If you don't want pathnname expansion or word splitting, you can turn them off: set -f; IFS=

set -f saved me in several lines, and IFS= broken me in more lines(have to restore it while creating array). I tried set -f only, but many lines still needed to be changed. So a more generic solution still needed. Currently, seems I've to keep bash setting by default and then check and modify lines one by one.

A shell is not a programming language, it's an environment from which to sequence calls to tools and manipulate (create/destroy) files and processes. Shell languages are designed to make writing instructions to do THAT task as concise as possible which is why many people trip over shell language semantics - they expect them to be similar to programming languages like C when they simply aren't, by design.

In a shell script written to do what you're supposed to use shell for it's usually most useful for quotes to behave the way they do by default, which is why that is the default behavior. If you find that's often not the case for your shell scripts then you should probably be using some other tool than shell for whatever it is you're trying to do.

Regarding "Sicne I already assigned x with "", why it cannot just treat x as quoted while parsing x" - as an example, suppose you write x="foo*" and later in your script wrote ls $x - the shell can't automatically know whether you REALLY wanted to output the string foo* (assuming a file of that name exists in your directory) or to output the list of files in the current directory that start with the string foo. If it assumed the former, you'd need some other constructs to do the latter. You just have to follow the shell quoting rules to make the shell do whichever you want it to do.
